# Are there some predefined directories for .tex file inclusion?

Tags: include

My question is simple, are there some predefined directories (in the *texmf* file system) where I can save my *.tex* files for further inclusions ?

> If yes :

- which ones are they ?
- Can I defined mine manually editing a configuration file ?

> If not :

- Is there some way to include a .tex file (placed anywhere on the
  disk) in a .tex file I write (anywhere on the disk too) ?

> For instance :

I'm writing a document located at `/media/XXX/documents/latex/foo/bar.tex`
And I need to include a file let's say located at `~/texmf/includes/style1.tex`

**ps** : and between include or input, which one seems more appropriate in my case ?

Comment: Your local `~/texmf` should mimic the structure of your installed 'tex tree'.  That means your personal LaTeX `.sty` files (and the like) should be located in `~/texmf/tex/latex/` (with further personal subdivisions if you like/need).  `.bib` files could be put in `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/`. And so on.  I made the following, e.g.: `mkdir -p ~/texmf/{bibtex,doc,fonts,tex,texdoc}` (some of these have sub-directories as well).

Comment: thanks for your answer but that doesn't really help to answer my question. where should I include my .tex include file ?

Comment: If it is a 'style' file as the name suggests, you 'should' give it a `.sty` extension (= style) and put it where I said the first time around.  If it is a regular `.tex` file containing text that will be printed as part of the main file, I would keep it in the same directory as your 'masterfile'.  And you should 'include' a `.sty` file in the preamble of your document; e.g., `\usepackage{style1}`.

Comment: You need to explain better what this included-from-elsewhere `.tex` file contains.  If it contains things like configuration parameters and `\newcommands` (etc.), then you can put it where I said and load it with `\usepackage`.  If, however, it is something like a chapter or section of text that you want to include in the body of a 'masterfile', then there are different reasons why you might want to use `\include` or `\input`.

Comment: `~/texmf/tex/latex/personal` is the preferred directory (the innermost one can have any name you like).

Comment: @egreg this is working nicely, can you post a short answer to validate the question ?

Comment: For MiKTeX users this should help: [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GNU/Linux systems using TeX Live, the best place for input files you commonly include is

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/personal
```

(in place of `personal` use any name you like), because this tree is always searched for input files and does not require any hashing (like in the main trees).

On Mac OS X with the MacTeX version of TeX Live, use

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/personal
```